# How to list files in particular order using command prompt?

Tags: command-prompt, dos

I need to list file of folder in below pattern

```
[filename] [size in GB] [Date] (eg: 29 Apr) [time](eg: 02:08)
```

using command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to use those properties as your sorting criteria, and don't need the output formatted in a particular way, `dir /O:NSD` will work. For more information, type `dir /?`.